# ReactJS - Importing component doesnt show up in DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im having a problem displaying the component I'm importing into my home.jsx file. No errors are being outputted.

**My component file**(header.jsx)**:**

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Import Styles.
import styles from './header.scss';

//Export Modules.
export default

class Navigation extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <header>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

**My main file**(home.jsx)**:**

```
//Import Dependencies.
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Import Styles.
import styles from './home.scss';

//Import Components.
import { Navigation } from '../../components/header.jsx'

//Export Modules.
export default

class HelloMessage extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="hello">Hello World!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**I'm rendering to the DOM like so**(home.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HelloMessage from './home.jsx';


ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know the paths are correct. I added a console.log into the component file and received it via development tools in chrome. Is it because I'm not directly binding it to a DOM element? I figured since my main file is being bound to an element it would to the same for my component? I guess I'm not sure how to bind it correctly? Sorry for the confusion, I'm new to React.js

Comment: What does your HTML look like? It could mean that there's no element that with an id of `root`.

Comment: I have the id in place. The HelloMessage element I created in home.jsx is being displayed. No Navigation component though.

Comment: I believe its due to not rendering the Navigation component to an actually DOM element. Not sure how to go about structuring that though.

Comment: @JoshSpears What you could do is use the HelloMessage component as a wrapper for your application (and also rename it to something along the lines of app/root) - in general I'd recommend having a single wrapper w. child components. Then import the navigation to the app/root component (now called HelloMessage), and every other child component and they'll get rendered since the app/root component is rendered through `ReactDom.render()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think you're saying that your `HelloMessage` component *is* displaying, but your `Navigation` component is not displaying, so I'll answer that bit.

When you do this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

...you're just telling React to bind whatever the `HelloMessage` component returns from its `render` method to that DOM element.  Even though you are importing your `Navigation` component, you are not actually rendering it so React doesn't really know it exists.  In order to render your `Navigation` component you'd need to do this in `home.jsx`:

```
// Import Dependencies.
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Import Styles.
import styles from './home.scss';

// Import Components.
import { Navigation } from '../../components/header.jsx'

// Export Modules.
export default

// Note that now `Navigation` is included in the render output
class HelloMessage extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation />
                <p className="hello">Hello World!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I just didn't know you could pass components into other components like that. However, I tried this and received a render error: ```Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `HelloMessage`.```

Comment: Hm that could mean that there is a problem with your `Navigation` component.  Are you sure that you're importing it from the right location according to your directory structure?

Comment: Yes, If I add a simple `console.log` to the header.jsx I see it outputting.

Comment: Oh it may be because you are doing a default export rather than a named export in `header.jsx` with `export default`.  Try importing Navigation without the brackets in `home.jsx`, like this: `import Navigation from '../../components/header.jsx'`

Comment: That worked! I dont understand though.. I thought when your importing custom modules you have to wrap them in curly brackets?

Comment: Great!  You only need to use the curly brackets when importing a "named" export.  A named export would look like this: `export class Navigation...` (notice no "default").  There's a lot of good info on ES2015 modules here:  http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html.